# If two nested open sets have the same nonempty boundary, are they the same set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $B_\epsilon(x)$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$. For $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, suppose that $V$ is an open set in $X$ with $V\subseteq B_\epsilon(x)$.

If $V$ and $B_\epsilon(x)$ share the same (nonempty) boundary, must they be the same set?

Comment: Discrete metric, fix $p$, $\varepsilon = 2$, $V = \{p\}$. Both have empty boundary. Maybe you want the boundary to be non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was not precise enough. I should have said "... share the same nonempty boundary,..." Your comment helps though.

Comment: The title seems to imply $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is an *open* ball, but it would make the Question's body more self-contained to insert that word there.

Comment: If you found that you should have said something else, **edit the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set with the Euclidean metric, and let $x=\epsilon=\frac13$. Then

$$B_\epsilon(x)=\left(0,\frac23\right)\cap X=\left(0,\frac13\right]\cap X\;,$$

whose boundary in $X$ is $\{0\}$. Let

$$V=\left(0,\frac29\right)\cap X=\left(0,\frac19\right]\cap X\;;$$

then $V$ is open in $X$, $V\subsetneqq B_\epsilon(x)$, and $\operatorname{bdry}V=\{0\}=\operatorname{bdry}B_\epsilon(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that bd($B_\epsilon(x)$) and bd($V$) are non-empty. Given, bd($B_\epsilon(x)$) = bd($V$). We have, $V \subseteq B_\epsilon(x)$.

Assume, if possible, that $x \notin V$ then $d(x,V)>0 \implies $ there exist $a \in bd(V)$ such that $d(x,a)=min_{z \in \overline{V}}{d(x,z)}>0$. Now, there exist an open ball around $a$ which lies entirely in $B_\epsilon(x)$(why?).
 Hence, $ a\notin bd(B_\epsilon(x))$, which is a contradiction to fact that $bd(B_\epsilon(x))=bd(V)$.

$\implies x \in V$. Similarly, for any $y \in B_\epsilon(x)$, the argument can be repeated. Therefore, $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq V$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am unable to see why there is an open ball around $a$ that is contained in $B_\epsilon(x)$.

Comment: You will find an open ball around a contained in $ B_{\epsilon}(x)$ because, $V \subset X$ and hence there exist $z \in \overline{V}$ such that $d(x,z)< \epsilon$. If $z \notin V$ then $a=z$ else, there exist $z_{1} \in \overline{V}$ such that $d(x,z_{1})<dx,z)<\epsilon$. Again, if $z_{1} \notin V$ then $z_{1}=a$. This will terminate as $V \subset B_{\epsilon}(x)$.